# ASP.NET site connects to remote via SSL from Visual Studio but not IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, ssl, iis-7

My question is: why does a dev site work when the project is run in Visual Studio 2010, but not when served from IIS on the same PC?

I am trying to set up a dev copy of a client's site. On startup, the site makes a connection to a remote database server. The connection uses WCF and a SSL certificate to secure it. When I installed the site on my PC, following instructions, I installed a Cert Chain into the "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and added registry keys and host entries to resolve connections to the remote service.

When I open the solution in Visual Studio 2010 on my PC and run it in the built-in ASP.NET dev server, it works -- my workstation connects to the remote service via SSL on a custom port (444) and the dev site queries for data successfully from the service. All of this is handled by a DLL provided with the project, and is outside my scope of work. I was briefed up front that the connection was very finicky about the SSL cert, system clock time agreement between the two machines, etc. and it took me a few tries to get it to work.

However, when I run the site in my local IIS (Windows 7, IIS 7.5) the site cannot connect to the remote service; the service won't accept the SSL connection. The startup code throws an exception when this happens, preventing the site from loading further.

Everything else seems to work fine: the only wrinkle is that VS requires a 32-bit version of the secure connection DLL while IIS on Windows 7 requires a 64-bit version. Both were provided to me and I swap them as required.

Comment: The exception has no stack trace from the origin; here is the code where it is thrown. I don't have access to source for the connection library (which is "XX_DataCon_Client").  
  
`if (ConfigSettings.WcfComChannelState == XX_DataCon_Client.Errors.UPDC_Errors.SSLNegotiateFailed)
{
 throw new Exception("An error occurred contacting the datasource provider.\r\nThe service is not available at the configured location.");
}`

Comment: Aha! It was the Cert Chain installation. I hadn't used certmgr before and accepted the default physical store of "Current User". The client tech contact walked me through re-doing it, selecting "Local Machine" instead. Now the IIS process also recognizes the SSL cert as trusted and the connection initialises OK.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment, the answer is: check that the Cert Chain (to trust the SSL certificate used by the WCF connection) is installed to Local Machine (so that IIS sees it), not just to Current User (account used by Visual Studio).